# Default param and Variable parameters in python

Tags: python, arguments, default-arguments

Following is my function :

```
def compare(a, b, key=None,*arg2):
    print(a,b,key)
```

So in this how do we call the function without specifying value for the key, but providing value for the arg2 tuple...

Thanks.

Comment: You don't.. Maybe you want to push the keyword to the end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \*\* (double star) and \* (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong You want to pass default value of variable key. If so you can change the order of the variables. like this

```
def compare(a, b,*arg2,key=None):
    print(a,b,key,arg2)

compare(2,3,12,134,135,35,4567647,67865)
#output: 2 3 None (12, 134, 135, 35, 4567647, 67865)
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work in case I do not want to send the key value... but what if i want to pass the value?
I mean, in some cases i do not want to pass, and in some use cases i would want to pass the 'key' value explicitly.

Comment: so you don't want to pass default value, then i am afraid i don't have any way to do that man.sorry:(